# how to convert a class with map to/from to a JSON string in js?

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is a problem I encountered at work recently. For example, i have a class such like

```
class A {
    map1: Map<number, number> = new Map();
    map2: Map<string, string> = new Map();
    // a bunch of other data
    age: number = 0;
    ...
}
```

i want to convert this class to/from a JSON string.
Why i want to do this: i want to make a function to recover data, so I want to save the data to a local text file.

1.

```
class A {
    map1: Map<number, number> = new Map();
    map2: Map<string, string> = new Map();
    test: number = 0;
    toMyString() {
        let context = '';
        context = '{'
            + '"map1":' + JSON.stringify([...this.map1.entries()])
            + ', "map2":' + JSON.stringify([...this.map2.entries()])
            + ', "test":' + JSON.stringify(this.test)
            + '}';
        return context;
    }
}
let a = new A();
a.map1.set(1, 1);
a.map1.set(2, 2);
a.map2.set('1', '1');
a.map2.set('2', '2');
let b = a.toMyString();
console.log('b: ', b);
let c = JSON.parse(b) as A;
console.log('c: ', c);     
c.map1 = new Map(c.map1);
c.map2 = new Map(c.map2);
console.log(c.toMyString()); // c.toMyString is not a function
```

2. 

```
class A {
    map1: Map<number, number> = new Map();
    map2: Map<string, string> = new Map();
    test: number = 0;
    toMyString() {
        let context: string[] = [];
        context.push('{"test":' + JSON.stringify(this.test)  + '}');
        context.push(JSON.stringify([...this.map1.entries()]));
        context.push(JSON.stringify([...this.map2.entries()]));
        return JSON.stringify(context);
    }
}
let a = new A();
a.map1.set(1, 1);
a.map1.set(2, 2);
a.map2.set('1', '1');
a.map2.set('2', '2');
let b = a.toMyString();
console.log('b: ', b);
let data: string[] = JSON.parse(b);
console.log('data: ', data);
let c: A = JSON.parse(data[0]) as A;
console.log('c: ', c);
c.map1 = new Map(JSON.parse(data[1]));
c.map2 = new Map(JSON.parse(data[2]));
console.log('c: ', c.test);
console.log('c: ', c);
c.map1 = new Map(c.map1);
c.map2 = new Map(c.map2);
let e = c.toMyString()   //  c.toMyString is not a function
console.log(e);
```

3. write down every property of A. But A has too many property

Comment: `JSON.parse()` by itself is not going to create Map values by itself. You can provide a "reviver" function as a second argument to `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: @Pointy it's useful. But how can i make the Object i get from JSON.parse() having toMyString() method

Comment: @Pointy i got it. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach I'd use here would be a static deserialization method. Any time you want to parse JSON into a class, you'll need to do some extra handling, and (while opinions may differ) this is often something you'll want to attach to the class itself.

```
class A {
    map1: Map<number, number> = new Map();
    map2: Map<string, string> = new Map();
    test: number = 0;
    toMyString() {
        let context = '';
        context = '{'
            + '"map1":' + JSON.stringify([...this.map1.entries()])
            + ', "map2":' + JSON.stringify([...this.map2.entries()])
            + ', "test":' + JSON.stringify(this.test)
            + '}';
        return context;
    }

    static fromJSON(input: string): A {
        const obj = JSON.parse(input);
        const instance = new A();
        instance.map1 = new Map(obj.map1);
        instance.map2 = new Map(obj.map2);
        return instance;
    }
}

const a = new A();
a.map1.set(1, 1);
a.map1.set(2, 2);
a.map2.set('1', '1');
a.map2.set('2', '2');
console.log(a.toMyString());

const serialized = a.toMyString();

const b = A.fromJSON(serialized);
console.log(b.toMyString());
```

Bonus: If you use `toJSON` instead of `toMyString` then `JSON.stringify(a)` will automatically use that function.